# GeoPandas, MatPlotLib, mapclassify plot with user defined bin

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I want to plot data that varies from 0 to 300 (not fixed) using geopandas. I will be keeping the interval for legend as

```
bins=[10,20,30,50,70,100,200]
```

But, here I am getting same color in the legend for the interval 70-100 and 100-200. How to get another color for the interval 100-200 even though no data available in that range?

```
shp.plot(column='rain', cmap='jet', scheme="User_Defined",
         legend=True, legend_kwds={'loc': 'upper right','fontsize':'x-small'},
         classification_kwds=dict(bins=[10,20,30,50,70,100,200]),
         ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Try a more discriminating [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791779/geopandas-userdefined-color-scheme-drops-colors) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65415390/geopandas-consistent-user-defined-color-scheme-for-subplots)